# Request to add inline code and monospace font

Tags: feature-request, markdown, inline-code

The title says it all. Could StackOverflow have the ability to insert "inlined code", as well as change the format of code blocks to be the browser's default monospace font?

Answer (score 6):

You can already insert in-lined code using backticks, `like <this>`.  Do you mean you want syntax highlighting on it?  If so, I disagree.  That would be remarkably distracting.

Comment: I don't think it would be incredibly distracting. I don't think it would help enough to be purposeful, but if implemented, I think it is something we would just all get used to.

Comment: I would support a slightly different background-color for inline code blocks.  right now they blend into the text too much IMHO

Answer (score 2):

This is a test of `inlined` code.

You see, `x + (y + z) == (x + y) + z`

(Use ``, if you want syntax highlighting, use a code block.)

Answer (score 0):

They will not use browser-default monospace font because Webkit-based browsers treat them differently than all the other browsers.

[[related uservoice request](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/107333-add-monospace-and-or-courier-to-the-code-font-family)]

Comment: A great article that discusses this http://www.alistapart.com/articles/howtosizetextincss