# "Inline code" button for the editor

Tags: support, editor, code-formatting, markdown, inline-code

I see bold and italics button but no inline code while it uses quite an uncommon syntax (back ticks, ``` `` ``` - the syntax is good, just not very obvious). It would be convenient to have this button.

Related but not the same: [Request to add inline code and monospace font](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7756/request-to-add-inline-code-and-monospace-font)

Comment: Should this be part of the FAQ?

Comment: I would upvote you 10x cuz I came especially here to figure that bloody inline highlighting out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just select the text like this and press the button to get `inline code text`.

Comment: As long as I've been using SO, I never knew you could do that. Awesome, +1! (I knew you could do it for a block, never thought to try it with just a selection.)

Comment: Great feature, just very well hidden :)