# Stack Overflow inline code

Tags: support, stack-overflow, inline-code

I'm a Stack Overflow n00b, but I believe it's an invaluable resource, and really has been so far to my deving on different projects.

Anyway, I have seen users write inline code.

In other words, they are in a comment or something like that, and they want to write some code such as $(document).ready(function(){});

Except, instead of having appear as plain text, it appears like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Except, inline.

Anyone want to inform me as to how I can get this to work?

Comment: Actually sorry guys, I found it right here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53209/inline-code-button-for-the-editor

Comment: I always thought that was for the code to be placed on a new line, but the button is smart enough to add inline or new line code depending on where your cursor is placed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help , which is linked from …

- the little `[?]` icon above the edit area
- in the editing sidebar where it says `full reference »`

The specific section you want is the one that says **Code Spans**

Comment: It isn't linked to anywhere from the "add comment" form though... Maybe a little [?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work) under the "Add Comment button...?

Comment: @Shog9 I think it's assumed if you're posting a comment you know the editing syntax, since you have to have written at least one post to 1) get enough rep to comment, or 2) have a post of your own to comment on

Comment: @Michael: yeah, but there's no indication that you can use the same syntax in comments (the post editor has that little toolbar and preview pane).

Comment: the link you mentioned does not have a code spans section

Comment: It seems you have to click the arrow next to "Code and Preformatted Text" before the stuff on code spans appears.

Comment: The question was about how it works not where it is documented. Why not include them both.

Answer (score 15):

What my somewhat pedantic friend meant to say was "use backticks" (~ key)

in line `this is my code this is my code` in line.

update: Since not everyone has an English keyboard layout and the backtick key may be missing, a good alternative is `ALT+96` (from numeric keypad) or just copy and paste this: `

Comment: It's incredible that this answer was missing. And the way you wrote it is even more incredible!

Comment: How do you use code tags in comments such as this though. <code>some code</code> doesn't work. EDIT: Figured it out, nvm.

Comment: @jan haha by `using backticks`?

Comment: I have a German keyboard without a numeric keypad. Every time I need to write inline code on Stack Exchange, I come here to copy and paste your backtick! `Thanks!`